# How to passing the parameter to event handle in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have created a component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AppStep from '../common/AppStep'
import { ButtonDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

class Step2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.togglePhoto = this.togglePhoto.bind(this);
        this.selectPhoto = this.selectPhoto.bind(this);

        this.toggleDoc = this.toggleDoc.bind(this);
        this.selectDoc = this.selectDoc.bind(this);


        this.state = {
          dropdownOpenDoc: false,
          dropdownOpenPhoto: false,
          valueDoc : "រូប​ថត",
          valuePhoto : "រូប​ថត"
        };


      }



    toggleDoc(event) {
        console.log(event.target.innerText)
        this.setState({
          dropdownOpenDoc: !this.state.dropdownOpenDoc
        });
      }
      selectDoc(event) {
          //console.log(event.target.innerText)
        this.setState({
          dropdownOpenDoc: !this.state.dropdownOpenDoc,
          valueDoc: event.target.innerText
        });

    }
    togglePhoto(event) {
        console.log(event.target.innerText)
        this.setState({
            dropdownOpenPhoto: !this.state.dropdownOpenPhoto
        });
      }
    selectPhoto(event) {
        //console.log(event.target.innerText)
      this.setState({
        dropdownOpenPhoto: !this.state.dropdownOpenDocPhoto,
        valuePhoto: event.target.innerText
      });

  }
    renderForm() {
        return (

            <form className="needs-validation"  name="loan-info" noValidate method="POST" action="/">
              <hr className="mb-4"/>

              <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">            
                    <div className="btn-group">

                        <ButtonDropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpenPhoto} toggle={this.togglePhoto}>
                                <DropdownToggle caret>{this.state.valuePhoto}</DropdownToggle>
                                <DropdownMenu>
                                        <DropdownItem onClick={this.selectPhoto}>ថត​ថ្មីពី​កាមេរា</DropdownItem>
                                        <DropdownItem onClick={this.selectPhoto}>ដាក់​រូប​ដែល​មាន​ស្រាប់</DropdownItem>
                                </DropdownMenu>
                        </ButtonDropdown>

                    </div>
                    <div id="photo-placholder">
                        <img className="img-placeholder-photo"  src="holder.js/312x225"/>

                        <div className="custom-camera" id="camera-photo">
                          <img className="img-placeholder" src="img/kanel.png"/>
                        </div>

                        <div className="custom-file" id="upload-photo" >
                          <input type="file" className="custom-file-input" id="photo-input-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" required />
                          <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="photo-input-file">
                              ជ្រើសរូបថត​អ្នក
                          </label>
                          <div className="invalid-feedback">
                              អ្នក​ចាំបាច់​បំពេញ ជ្រើសរូបថត
                          </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">            
                    <div className="btn-group">
                    {/* Render another dropdown list */}

                    <ButtonDropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpenDoc} toggle={this.toggleDoc}>
                                <DropdownToggle caret>{this.state.valueDoc}</DropdownToggle>
                                <DropdownMenu>
                                        <DropdownItem onClick={this.selectDoc}>ថត​ថ្មីពី​កាមេរា</DropdownItem>
                                        <DropdownItem onClick={this.selectDoc}>ដាក់​រូប​ដែល​មាន​ស្រាប់</DropdownItem>
                                </DropdownMenu>
                        </ButtonDropdown>

                    </div>
```

I want to add more dropdown list which has difference display,I don't want to copy the same functions , anyone could guide how can just pass the params and handle its output.

Thanks

Comment: To be clear, you want to pass additional parameters into your toggle method?

Comment: Where is the additional parameters coming from?

Comment: when I need to add a new dropdown list , my current approach is duplicate function toggle and select for example toggle1, select1 or toggle2, select2

Comment: oh, so the dropdown is causing an event; but, there can multiple dropdowns that can send the event. So you want to be able to figure out which dropdown sent the event right?

Comment: @Tyler , I have updated my trying snippet code, please kindly check.

Comment: `event.target` is different from `event.currentTarget`. `target` can potentially point to an element that did not call the event due to event bubbling. As a result, it can create unpredictable results. You should use `currentTarget`, as `currentTarget` is predictable. It will ALWAYS refer to the element that raised the event.

Comment: my trying to use only 2 function toggle() and select() with param for example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I am correct at this [comment](http://BindClickedData), I believe you can solve your problem with `event.currentTarget`. This is a vanilla javascript thing, here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

Essentially, `event.currentTarget` always refers to the exact element that raised the event. So it will always refer to the specific dropdownlist that raised your toggle event.

Note, do NOT confuse `event.target` with `event.currentTarget`. `event.target` has varying results; because, the element it can refer to can change due to things like event bubbling.

Comment: anyways to simplify the code, by for example toggle(param, event) , select(param, event) and I can pass it through each dropdown element.

Comment: @kn3l I'm not following what you are saying. Could describe what is the extra param you are trying to pass in and where it is coming from?